# Internal view Mod for X3: Terran Conflict?

Tags: mods, x3-terran-conflict

Anyone knows a Mod for a Internal View in X3: Terran Conflict ? I mean, from inside the Ship.

Sorry for my crappy English.

Answer (score 1):

There are many [cockpit mods](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=241761) that change the views from within ships to have a more unique experience.

There are also a few [HUD mods](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=242903) that can tweak the information you see inside the cockpit.